# How to install Windows Media Player to European Version of Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

As you know, European versions of Windows 7 do not have Windows Media Player and Internet Explorer 8 preinstalled. Does anyone know how to install the latest WMP on the European version of Windows 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you'll want to go to [this website](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windowsmedia/download/AllDownloads.aspx?displang=en&qstechnology=) and hit the option under Windows 7. FYI - The Euro version of Windows w/o media player is referred to as "Windows N".

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried finding it either via Windows Update or from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windowsmedia/player/default.aspx) the media player webpage.